# How to turn off GDB's ref command?

Tags: gdb, ref

When using GDB, "ref" command displays source code which is quite useful. But I can't use short key like up arrow when being in this mode. Is there a way to turn off this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `refresh` command enters `TUI` mode.

If you do `info win`, you'll see something like:

```
(gdb) info win
    SRC     (53 lines)  <has focus>
    CMD     (26 lines)
```

The cursor keys scroll the window that has focus, which is why they reposition source but don't allow you to recall previous commands at the `(gdb)` prompt. So switch focus back to the prompt with `focus cmd`, and voila: you can use arrow keys as if you were outside the `TUI` mode.

You can also leave the `TUI` mode completely with `C-x C-a`, `C-x a` or `C-x A` keystroke. [Documentation for TUI](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_195.html).